# Redisson keeps many threads running

Tags: spring-boot, redis, redisson

I am using springboot-redission for simple caching operations, using redission client as singleton bean (spring bean), i see thread dump many redission related threads are active. Is it because i keep the redisson client open always?.

is it recommended to open and close the  client?, so each request would open and close the connection.

[image: redisson]

Comment: Are you experiencing any kind of performance issues due to these threads?

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce threads amount via `nettyThreads` setting.